# Is text API in HTML5 canvas still so slow?

Tags: html, canvas

I have read some articles about text API in canvas being slow in browsers. These articles are a year old, was there some improvement over this time? Does for example Google use canvas Text API in its Google Maps MapsGL?

Comment: Why don't you test them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I profiled this on [my site](http://www.structuredcanvaslanguage.com/ProfilingJS/) recently using fillText() and strokeText():

fillText()

1. 157.1ms  Safari 5.1.7
2. 215.8ms  Chrome v21
3. 210.6ms  Chrome v22
4. 426.1ms  IE 9 (64bit)
5. 994.5ms  FireFox 15.0.1  994.

strokeText()

1. 196.6ms  Chrome v21
2. 193.0ms  Chrome v22
3. 3793.1ms  IE 9 (64bit)
4. 6149.0ms  FireFox 15.0.1
5. 9628.8ms  Safari 5.1.7

Yes, I think slow but really browser dependent. Test test code there and you can run it yourself but actually, FF may time out waiting for test to complete.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at Google Maps GL, one can see that it uses a file called https://maps.gstatic.com/cat_js/intl/en_ALL/mapfiles/435c/maps2/%7Bmain,mod_util,mod_vt%7D.js

In that, there are indeed calls to fillText(), there are 6 instances of "fillText" in the file.

Comment: Thanks, I have also replicated test: http://simonsarris.com/blog/322-canvas-drawtext-considered-harmful and it looks, that at least Chrome is now better with font caching.

Comment: Good article, bookmarked - thank-you! The js code used for the maps is larger than I've the inclination(or brain-power) to examine just now. It wouldn't surprise me if they used this trick. I didn't think to check how many times the code creates a canvas. Though simply blitting pixels _should_ always be faster than drawing text - unless of course there is a hardware-text capability. I've seen similar advice regarding copying images from 1 canvas to another, rather than drawing an <img> to a canvas. Rep++ for the link.